# SQL Server Decimal division returning 1.000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to calculate some percentage based off a total value of email sends. I've been struggling to work out why my division calculation isn't returning my expected result.

I am trying to return the values of percentages for each item relating to the total sends. E.g. Unsubscribes/total sends = 0.1% |

I've been looking at this all day and can't seem to progress past this point, so I really think I've missed something so small and stupid.

Here is a picture of the query/results displaying the problem:

[image]

Before the FROM, I have commented a couple of lines which I had written to attempt to fix this problem, please don't laugh at me! :P

```
SELECT
    'Unsubscribes' AS 'Type',
    COUNT(e.eventid) AS 'Total',
    -- e2.all_values AS 'Total',
    -- ISNULL(NULLIF(COUNT(CAST(e.eventid AS DECIMAL(15,2))), 0) / 
    COUNT(CAST(e2.all_values as decimal(15,2))),0) AS '%',
    -- CAST(COUNT(e.EventID) as decimal(15,2)) / CAST(COUNT(e2.all_values) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS '%'
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e.EventID)) /  CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), 
    COUNT(e2.all_values)) AS '%'
    COUNT(e2.all_values))
FROM 
    XMPDBTRACKING.XMPieTracking.Event e
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         COUNT(e2.eventid) AS 'all_values',
         MarketingCampaignID
     FROM 
         xmpdbtracking.xmpietracking.event e2
     WHERE 
         e2.marketingcampaignid = 16704
         AND e2.eventtypeid IN (20)
     GROUP BY 
         MarketingCampaignID) e2 ON e2.MarketingCampaignID = e.MarketingCampaignID
 WHERE 
     e.MarketingCampaignID = 16704
     AND e.EventTypeID IN (24)
```

I am trying to return the value of Unsubscribes/Total Sends as the % Value

```
Total Send  4366    100.000000000000000000
Unsubscribes    65  1.000000000000000000
```

Comment: "isn't returning my expected result.": which would be?

Comment: Well, looking at this calculation - CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e.EventID)) /  CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e2.all_values)) AS '%'. It should relate to 65/4366 = 0.014887769.....

Comment: Instead of liberally casting everywhere, which makes it hard to detect where something might be going wrong, try multiplying by `1e` before a division to force a floating-point calculation, and cast the results only at the end for presentation (if necessary). (This is not "the" solution in general, since sometimes you really want `DECIMAL` calculations of a particular precision to prevent rounding problems, but this does not appear to be one of those cases.)

Comment: Honestly I am pretty sure you are needing a `SUM` and not `COUNT` but it's hard to tell without any sample data.

Comment: @JacobH I have included an Imgur link to a screenshot of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e.EventID)) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e2.all_values)) AS '%'
```

to:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e.EventID)) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), COUNT(e2.all_values)) AS '%
```

Maybe it's because of the fact that the result of a count is integer and not decimal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing that information. I completely understand your reasoning, I have implemented this below and I am now returning the same results but with two decimal places rather than 40!

Comment: Total Send 4366 100.00
Unsubscribes 65 1.00

Answer (score 0):

Your main query counts the unsubscribes, right?
The LEFT outer join means that it will only match rows that exist in the main query. So you query only the "unsubscribes".

How about this (untested):

```
;WITH sums AS
(
  SELECT MarketingCampaignID
  ,      SUM(CASE EventTypeID WHEN 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Event20
  ,      SUM(CASE EventTypeID WHEN 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Event24
  GROUP BY MarketingCampaignID
)
SELECT MarketingCampaignID
,      CAST(Event24 as decimal(15,2)) / CAST(Event20 AS decimal(15,2))
FROM sums
```